# script to run exe as specific user in windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file, exe

I have a .exe file in some location C:/foo/myhost.exe which actually creates MSMQ queues in the system and I need to run that a specific user (Network account). I am looking for script where business user can login to the server click the exe(But it should run as network account). I can shift-right-click on exe but I am looking to automate it.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: here I've tried to use `SCHTASKS` and `EVENTCREATE` to do such thing: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1539 .You can check if this will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runas with savecred option

http://anyadangtech.blogspot.ca/2009/06/runas-without-password.html

But you need to run the first time to input the passwd. Afterwards it will remember the passwd.